# Memcached for fragment cachine in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, memcached

I'm trying to figure out the best way to set organize the caching system for my scenario:

My web app has "trending movies," which are basically like twitter's trending topics -- the popular topics of conversation.  I've written the function `Movie.trending`, which returns an array of 5 `Movie` objects.  However, since calculating the trending movies is fairly CPU intensive and it will be shown on every page, I want to cache the result and let it expire after 5 minutes.  Ideally, I'd like to be able to call `Movie.trending` from anywhere in the code and assume that cachine will work how i expect it to -- if the results are 5 minutes or earlier, then renew the results, otherwise, serve the cached results.

Is fragment caching the right selection for a task like this?  Are there any additional gems I ought to be using?   I'm not using Heroku.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To reach this model's caching you can try Rails.cache.fetch, see the example below:

```
# model - app/models/movie.rb
class Movie
  def self.trending
    Rails.cache.fetch("trending_movies", :expires_in => 5.minutes) do
      # CPU intensive operations
    end
  end
end

# helper - app/views/helpers/application.rb
module ApplicationHelper
  def trending_movies
    content_tag :div do
      Movie.trending
    end
  end
end

# view - app/views/shared/_trending_movies
trending_movies
```

To test it in development mode don't forget to turn on caching for a specific environment